# Objective C equivalent of C method signature

Tags: objective-c

I want make a function to include in my code to calculate percentages.

In Php, it's :

```
function percent(a,b){
  return a/b*100;
}
```

In Objective C, I don't know. I tried:

```
-(void)percent(a,b){
   return a/b*100;
}
```

But there are 2 errors. Could you me explain how to make it work?

Thank you for you help

Comment: Before starting to write code, I would like to recommend to read a little bit about the syntax of the language. Obj-C method syntax is different, so it's natural to get confused but the way you have tried indicates that you have not read a single line about method syntax in Obj-C.

Comment: Saying "there are 2 errors" is not enough. You need to state which errors they are.

Comment: Thank you at all.

It's the first time that y post here and i'm very pleasantly surprised.

For information, I managed to make a application with Json with RestKit but I had not encountered this problem.
I am quite willing to read documentation on the programming but I think in the circumstances of use, the syntax can vary greatly. This is just the beginning.

I like already.

Thank you for your welcome.

Alex

Comment: @AlexandreOuicher Glad we could surprise you :) I figure I'll mention this since you said you're new to SO: Whenever you get a chance to go through these, be sure to come back and mark whichever answer helped *you* the most as the "answer" with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more correct way to do this will be:

```
- (float)precentageByDevidingFloat:(float)a byFloat:(float)b {
  float returnValue = 0; 
  if (b != 0)
    returnValue = a / b * 100;

  return returnValue;

}
```

This way you use a more correct naming convention , you actually return a float and your safe in case some one gave you the value 0 in B.
(which should be covered by documentation)

Comment: One might be interested to return `NaN` if `b == 0`.

Comment: You don't have to check for 0, the function will return infinity if `b = 0`, floats don't behave like integers when divided by 0.

Answer (score 2):

A method is defined in a slightly different syntax than you're used to:

```
- (float)percentWithA:(float)a dividedByB:(float)b
{
    return a / b * 100;
}
```

The parameters are "strewn" throughout the method call. For instance, this method's name would be `percentWithA:dividedByB:`. You don't need to be as explicit as this call, however. For example, you *could* do this:

```
- (float)percent:(float)a :(float)b { /* ... */ }
```

But it doesn't provide much context.

Comment: You beat me. Will delete mine :)

Comment: If you covered anything I didn't, feel free to keep your answer. :)

Comment: No need. I just included a pointer to the ObjC intro doc which I think our man definitely needs to read: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks for the heads up, I fail. Code has been updated.

Comment: Very true...I wonder if I should even be programming today? /fail

Comment: At least you're programming, not operating a steam hammer or performing heart surgery :)

Comment: Also true. At any rate, thanks for pointing that oversight out @TimKemp.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this, with a C function:

```
// in your .h
float percent(float a, float b);

// in your .m or .c
float percent(float a, float b)
{
    return a / b * 100.0f;
}
```

Or, if you are into macros:

```
// remember to always enclose macros in parentheses
#define percent(a, b) (a / b * 100.0f)
```

And you would call it like this:

```
percent(50, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C uses a strange convention of having parameter names as part of a method name and therefore parameter declarations are embedded in a method name.

```
-(float)percentOf:(float)a over:(float)b 
{
    return (a/b) * 100.0;
}
```

The first type in parentheses defines the return type, the parameters come after colons and also have their type in parentheses.

Comment: It's not a "strange" convention, it's how people have decided to materialize the difference between the concept of "having a method" (what traditonnal OO languages do) and "being able to receive/handle a message" (what ObjectiveC does).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII you are of course correct, forgive me for using the normal UK usage of the term bracket. You might want to look at the OP who used the phrase "I want make a function"

Comment: @Romain, it is strange, do any other languages use the convention?

Comment: @brain Smalltalk anyone? Message passing languages aren't so frequent though, but it's a different paradigm, hence different notations.

Comment: @Romain, So Smalltalk and Objective-C (derived from Smalltalk). Nowhere near as common as functioName(arg1, arg1) style.

Comment: @brain I'm not saying it's "common". I'm saying it's "not weird" because it actually means something different. The two semantics are *not* equivalent.